# Session always regenerates in ionic 3 / angular 4

Tags: php, angular, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, ionic3

I want to make cart in codeigniter 3 using angular 4 / ionic 3

but I cannot add cart successfully, as the cart is always refreshing and makes a new cart again and again

JS :

```
addCart(id, menu, harga) {
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers
    });
    let body = JSON.stringify({id : id ,menu : menu, harga:harga});
    return this.http.post(this.apiAddCart, body,options).toPromise()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

PHP/ Codeigniter :

```
public function add_cart() {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,OPTIONS");
        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        $postdata       = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $request        = json_decode($postdata);

        $data = array(
            'id'    => $request->id,
            'name'  => $request->menu,
            'price' => $request->harga,
            'qty'   => 1
        );
        $add = $this->cart->insert($data);
        var_dump($this->cart->contents());
    }
```